# AppBar contents are wrong after refresh or hitting back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using ReactJS with Material-UI, which I am both quite new to using.

I have an [AppBar](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) component that is used as a main menu/navigation bar. I would like the title of the AppBar component to reflect the page I'm on. So if I press a button that routes the user to /login , I also want to change the title of the AppBar component to "Login". I have accomplished this but there seem to be some side effects so I doubt it's the proper practice.

At the moment, my AppBar component looks like so:

```
render() {
    let MenuOptionsNotLogged = ({}) => (
        <div>
            <FlatButton
                label="Log In"
                containerElement={<Link to="/login" />}
                secondary
                linkButton
                onClick={this.switchToLogin}
            />
        </div>
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                <div className="headerDiv">
                    <AppBar
                        className="appBar"
                        showMenuIconButton={this.state.appBarIcon}
                        title={this.state.appBarTitle}
                        iconElementRight={<MenuOptionsNotLogged />}
                        iconElementLeft={<IconButton><BackIcon /></IconButton>}
                    />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
```

In my constructor, I set the default state of the AppBar(the title and icon):

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.switchToLogin = this.switchToLogin.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        appBarTitle: 'Home',
        appBarIcon: false
    };
}
```

And then I have a function which changes the title and icon when the user navigates to the Login page:

```
switchToLogin() {
    this.setState({ appBarTitle: 'Log in' });
    this.setState({ appBarIcon: true });
}
```

**The problem**

This 'works', but it has some problems if the user refreshes or hits the back button on their browser.

E.g. user navigates to /login, title changes to "Login", user refreshes browser. Then the user will be on /login but the title will reset to "Home".

Same problem with the back button. User can navigate to login, press back, and the title will stay as "Login" as opposed to "Home"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have a `Link` component. My answer assumes you use `react-router`.

The problem is that your `appBarTitle` state is not mapped correctly with the current route.
Also when user refresh the browser, the `state` of components resets.

if you are not using `reat-router 3.0`, you can get access to the current route through `this.context.location.pathname`. You will need to read about how to use `context` [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Then you can write a helper function to map pathname to the text you want to display: `'/login' -> 'Login', '/' -> 'Home'`.

Then the `title` of your `AppBar` can just be the value returned from the helper function. You no longer need to keep tract of it in the state.

Just to add, not relating to your question, Reactjs is a declarative style of programming, meaning that, 'switchToLogin then display login title' is discouraged. Tell the component what to render rather than how to.

Comment: @Rolodecks 'If `contextTypes` is not defined, then context will be an empty object.' quoting from [react docs][https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html]. To fix it, define `contextTypes` for your component. `router` can just be an object

Comment: @xiafan2406 , i defined contextTypes for both router, as so: 

`MenuBar.contextTypes = {
 router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};`

but still seem to be having issues, is this correct?

edit:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Comment: @Rolodecks, my mistake, for latest stable version of `react-router` (2.5.2) it should be `this.context.location.pathname`. I have amended my answer

Comment: @xiafan2406 thank you. should 'location' be defined as an object as well within contextTypes?

Comment: thanks for the help. i made a helper function that returns the correct title based on the value of `this.context.location.pathname`, but i am confused as to how i get the component to update when i route to a different screen. if i navigate to `/login`, the title will still be set to "Home" unless i refresh the page.